# Ember Selectbox select a child association in a form

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Having trouble with selecting a belongsTo association to it's parent via a select box on an input form.

Model in question

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  proNumber: DS.attr('number'),
  status: DS.attr('string'),
  special: DS.attr('string'),
  customer: DS.belongsTo('customer', { async: true }),
  carrier: DS.belongsTo('carrier', { async: true }),
  equipmentList: DS.belongsTo('equipment-list', { async: true}),
  stops: DS.hasMany('stop'),
  loadRates: DS.hasMany('load-rate'),
  grossPay: Ember.computed.mapBy('loadRates', 'rate'),
  totalGrossPay: Ember.computed.sum('grossPay')
});
```

Model that I'm trying to associate is customer above.

input - from Material - works exactly like most selectbox Ember addons

```
  {{md-select content=customerList
     value=model.customer  <-- doesn't work
     label="Customer"
     prompt="Please Choose a Customer..."
     optionLabelPath='content.name'
     optionValuePath='content.id'}}
```

The value doesn't work.

Comment: Are you comparing by id? Perhaps it's `value=model.customer.id` ?

Comment: @GSP That gives `me Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: A record's id cannot be changed once it is in the loaded state`

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you either need to change

```
optionValuePath='content.id'
```

to

```
optionValuePath='content'
```

or don't have the line at all. Then maybe the component supports the property "selection" instead of "value" as many select-components do.

I've had a similar problem for a different select component and a little different case which I would like to add here since I know I stumbled on this thread when trying to solve my problem. How I solved it was through the following. I had a "question" which has many answer where one of them can be selected as the "correct answer".

```
answers: DS.hasMany('answer'),
correctAnswer: DS.belongsTo('answer'),

correctAnswerId: Ember.computed('correctAnswer', 'correctAnswer.id', {
    get() {
        return this.get('correctAnswer.id');
    },
    set(key, value) {
        this.set('correctAnswer', this.get('answers').findBy('id', value));
        return value;
    }
}),
```

Answer (score -1):

belongsTo means it is a single object. Not an array like object.

Why would you want to use a select box for a single object?

Comment: Other way around.  Customer hasMany loads.  On the load I select a single customer.